# Binding to elements in WPF GridViewHeader doesn't work

Tags: wpf, gridview, binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a custom header for a ListView / GridView where the user can easily filter items using Text inputs:

I've created DependencyProperties on the UserControl's code-behind and are binding the Xaml datacontext to itself (name=root). The binding i'm having trouble with is the TextBox inside the Header - it simply doesn't work. If i set a 'ModelVariantId' to "Whatever" it doesn't show and likewize i don't get any PropertyChanged events when writing in it..

I've found -some- similar sounding questions on the internet but nothing exactly matching.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=CombinedCarModels}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ModelVariantId}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Label>ModelVariantId</Label>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=root, 
                                Path=CarModelFilter.ModelVariantId, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a `HeaderTemplate`, this binding should work:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, 
    Path=CarModelFilter.ModelVariantId, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

**XAML:**

```
<GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">ModelVariantId</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=CarModelFilter.ModelVariantId, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

There is no element named "root" in the same naming scope as the header, but you should be able to bind to a parent element in the visual tree using the `RelativeSource` property.

This assumes that the parent `UserControl` has a `CarModelFilter` property.

Comment: The parent is correctly a UserControl and it Does have a CarModelFilter property.. but your suggestion doesn't work - the binding can't find the CarModelFilter property.
Maybe it can't find the ancestor ?

Comment: You need to put in a `DataTemplate`. See my edit. You might also have to set the `Header` property to something else than `null`.